# Moving Kali Linux Persistent Installation to another USB drive

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, persistence

I have a 8GB USB Drive where I installed Kali Linux (4GB partition) and then used the other 4GB for the persistent part.

Yesterday I did an "apt update && apt upgrade" and it crashed my system. At the time it seemed that there was more than enough space for the updates but today I boot the system, choose the Persistence installation, put my password for the encrypted drive and then I get a black screen with a blinking arrow instead of the login screen.

I think it ran out of space...

I have a 64GB USB Drive and I wanted to move the installation to there to have more space. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it, and I'm able to change the size of the persistence partition on the new drive?

Comment: Generally with persistent live systems you can keep the home directory with tweaks and personal files, but it is best to create a fresh persistent live system (and install the program packages you want to add). I think it is too difficult (not worth the effort) to repair a crashed persistent live system unless you have a backup of the system, when it was still working.

Comment: Thank you for the response Sudodus. I didn't want to start a new system because of all the setup that I've made on that one, but I guess I will have to do it... I was able to login via the normal boot and as root, I could delete some files to free up some space. Now I have more than 500MB of free storage but I still can't see the login  box on the persistence boot up, I can only see the mouse arrow and the desktop wallpaper.

Comment: Try backup of your next persistent live system according to these links (Test that it works with a similar USB drive.) [Backup & restore of the home directory in a casper-rw partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_.26_restore_of_the_home_directory_in_a_casper-rw_partition) and [Backup & restore of the whole casper-rw partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_.26_restore_of_the_whole_casper-rw_partition) -- Please notice that these tools target Ubuntu persistent live systems, and you may have to tweak them to work with Kali Linux.